# in past years / in the past years

Tags: difference, articles

> *In past years* Mr. Jones, although a hard master, had been a capable farmer...

I'm wondering if *in past years* can be replaced with *in the past years*? Do they have the same meaning or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*in the past years*" is [uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+past+years%2Cin+the+past+years%2Cin+the+past+few+years&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20past%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20past%20few%20years%3B%2Cc0) compared to "*in past years*" or the more common "*in the past **few** years*". It sounds like a mish-mash of the other two.

"*In past years*" is usefully vague referring to **some** years: not necessarily recent or *successive* ones.

"*in the past few years*" means a number of recent, **successive** years.